# Add the toc to the toc with the correct section numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I have had problems with the bibliography title and the Table-of-contents title not being numbered and not showing in the ToC. To solve it I used the [tocbibind](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf) package.

By adding the line:

```
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
```

to my preamble both the bibliography title and the ToC title appeared in the ToC. And the `numbib` value added a numbering to the bibliography.

I am still missing the numbering of the ToC, though:

[image]

As you can see in the ToC list the "Contents" title appears as it should but without a numbering. The "Contents" title (in red) *did* get a number though, when I added this package, but the number is wrong. As you can see, it has the number `2`, which is already taken by the "Preface" title.

So it seems the numbering is not working properly and in any case not added to the ToC. Looking through the documentation of the tocbibind package, I couldn't find any notion of this, but if it *can* be fixed with this package, that would be good. Else, how can I fix this?

---

My code structure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
 ...
\begin{document}

   \section{Abstract}
   Text text text

   \section{Preface}
   Text text text

   \pagebreak
   \tableofcontents
   \pagebreak

   \section{Introduction}
   Text text text
   ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tocbibind` has no provision for numbering the table of contents. The easiest method is to redefine `\tableofcontents` to do it and to load `tocbibind` with the `nottoc` option in order to avoid double inclusion.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section{\contentsname}\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

   \section{Abstract}
   Text text text

   \section{Preface}
   Text text text

   \clearpage
   \tableofcontents
   \clearpage

   \section{Introduction}
   Text text text
   ...
\end{document}
```

Notes. (1) Avoid `utf8x`. (2) If you want a page break that fills the available space, use `\clearpage`; `\pagebreak` seems to work here, but just because `\raggedbottom` is in force: with the `twoside` option you'd get surprises.

[image: picture]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Would you clarify for me why `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are necessary?

Comment: @Steeven See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/)